# Tornado server with RPC client

Tags: websocket, rabbitmq, tornado, rpc

I need a server which receive connections from browsers via websocket. Something like this

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.websocket
from tornado import template

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('index.html')

class WebSocket(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True

    def open(self):
        print("WebSocket opened")

    def on_message(self, message):
        self.write_message(message)

    def on_close(self):
        print("WebSocket closed")


class Application(tornado.web.Application):
     def __init__(self):
        handlers = ((r'/', MainHandler),(r'/websocket/?', WebSocket),
                   (r'/static/(.*)', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler,
                   {'path': 'static/'}),)
     tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, debug=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     application = Application()
     application.listen(8888)
     tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

After a message has been received it should be passed to the RPC-client that sends it to RabbitMQ and receives a response. Then this response goes to the browser. How to do it?

I guess that the RPC-client should start as a separate process and the socket should be passed from the server to the RPC-client. But how to do it?

Perhaps Tornado has built-in possibilities to do something like this.